# functions that has :: at the beginning

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

what does :: means at the start of a functions like ::mesagebox, ::PostQuitMessage, ::DestroyWindow and etc? i was reading a book called Introduction to 3D Game Programming with DirectX 9.0 and when i look at the example source code, it has so many functions that has :: on it.

here is the example code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK d3d::WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch( msg )
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        ::PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        if( wParam == VK_ESCAPE )
            ::DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    }
    return ::DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: bare `::` at the begining indicates the operand is member of global namespace.

Comment: I'm always curious about what programmer *seriously* considered that some other programmer would create a new PostQuitMessage in the local namespace.

Comment: @ZanLynx - I agree, although we do have an MFC version of `DestroyWindow()` and an ATL version of `DefWindowProc()` so probably safer to be explicit for everything.